# Message: /dev/sda5 clean, blocks

Tags: boot, 16.04

Once released computer before I loaded Ubuntu I get the following:

> **/dev/sda5: clean, 21758/3057824 files, 1500295/1224512 blocks**

Then only then charging. Any idea how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal, it's showing that your main partition `/dev/sda5` is being checked for filesystem errors, by `fsck`, on every boot. In older versions of Ubuntu, the checks used to be after a specific time period or number of reboots. It appears that checking the disk on every boot is the default behaviour for 16.04.